# I can't save using JPA repository. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've a model User. I can't save an user from postman using JPA repository.
Please tell me what am I doing wrong here. I'm sending post request from postman using localhost:8080/api/add_user

This is the table.

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_user` (
    `user_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `contact` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    `category` ENUM('general', 'star', 'gold', 'platinum') NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY (`contact`)
);
```

This is the model.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    long userId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;

    @Column(name = "email")
    String email;

    @Column(name = "contact")
    String contact;

    @Column(name = "category")
    String category;

    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getContact() {
        return contact;
    }
    public void setContact(String contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }
    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public User() {
    }
}
```

This is the controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserRestController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add_user}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public User addUser(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, @RequestBody User user) {
        return userService.addUser(user);
    }

}
```

Repository and Service

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}

@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    public User addUser(User user) {
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Project is running without error. when I'm hitting url through postman using POST, I'm getting error. please tell me what am I doing wrong.

I'm sending this from postman using url localhost:8080/api/add_user

```
{
    "name": "Bonku",
    "email": "bonku@gmail.com",
    "contact": "01725164100",
    "category": "general"
}
```

and getting this back

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-04-26T11:11:56.756+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/api/add_user"
}
```

this is the url I'm hitting now from postman :

```
localhost:8080/api/users/add
```

This is the error

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-04-26T11:30:11.695+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "error performing isolated work; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work",
    "trace": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: error performing isolated work; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:279)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:138)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)\r\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.save(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat com.project.service.UserService.addUser(UserService.java:40)\r\n\tat com.project.controller.UserRestController.addUser(UserRestController.java:45)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\r\nCaused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work\r\n\tat org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:79)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1.getNextValue(TableStructure.java:125)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:40)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:482)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:119)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:192)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:62)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:799)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350)\r\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.persist(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:308)\r\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.persist(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:489)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)\r\n\t... 65 more\r\nCaused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'spring_boot_project_factory_1_db.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:970)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1020)\r\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)\r\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure.executeQuery(TableStructure.java:216)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure.access$300(TableStructure.java:46)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1.execute(TableStructure.java:138)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1.execute(TableStructure.java:126)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.jdbc.WorkExecutor.executeReturningWork(WorkExecutor.java:55)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractReturningWork.accept(AbstractReturningWork.java:34)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:57)\r\n\t... 105 more\r\n",
    "path": "/api/users/add"
}
```

Comment: Which error you are getting?

Comment: How your config looks like, are you using in memory db like h2?

Comment: Is it possible that you have created the table and not JPA itself? Because in your CreateTable you made use of an enum, but I cannot see an enum in your Entity User

Comment: I updated with error. please have a look, I'm using mysql.

Comment: Ok, so after you edited the question we can see you are getting 404, which doesn't have anything with your db, it is about your controller, going to try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete underscore from the path, it is unsafe url character. Because it is `UserRestController`, I would design that api like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users/")
public class UserRestController {

   @Autowired
   UserService userService;

   @PostMapping(value = "add")
   public User addUser(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, @RequestBody User user) {
       return userService.addUser(user);
   }

}
```

Try it like that

**Edit**

Ok, first problem (404) is resolved now you have sql exception.
You should create your enum in new file like:

```
public enum Category {
   general, 
   star, 
   gold, 
   platinum
}
```

than change:

```
@Column(name = "category")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
Category category;

//and change this
public Category getCategory() {
     return category;
}

public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;
}
```

try that.

And change sql:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_user` (
`user_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`email` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`contact` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
`category` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
UNIQUE KEY (`contact`)
);
```

Comment: Sir, the error has changed, but still not getting entered.

Comment: Ok, 404 is resolved with my suggestion, now you have sql exception

Comment: You had 404, that is resolved, writing the answer for second issue, going to edit my answer

Comment: Yes, try now. First you had 404 error, now you have 500, so first thing is done

Comment: And change your sql as well, alter the table or rewrite

Comment: You can alter it, run the sql: ALTER TABLE tbl_user MODIFY category VARCHAR(15);

Comment: And let me know here if you have more issues @SubhaBhowmik

Comment: Sir, Changing the @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) has done the work for me. I've the restriction to not change the table structure. Your suggestion also worked. Thanks a lot for your help.